# place value automatically to third field by adding values from first and second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, input

I need to add value to third field after getting value from first and second. 
To be more clear, I have some code below:

```
<input type="text" name="first_date" class="datepicker" date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" id="first_date" />
<select name="duration">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="6">6 months</option>
    <option value="12">12 months</option>
    <option value="18">18 months</option
</select>

<input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
```

I'm working for dates and have used datepicker (jquery). I need to add 6 or 12 or 18 or 24 months to the date picked in #first_date and display the date after addition of duration in the third field #end_date

And also the value should change on change of selection(option).
How can I make it work? I searched but couldn't find the solution I was looking for. Any helps?

Comment: I tried some scripts but didn't work. I'm new to jquery,javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function updateEndDate(){
    var sdate = $('#first_date').datepicker('getDate'), duration = parseInt( $('select[name="duration"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    if(sdate){
        var edate = new Date(sdate.setMonth(sdate.getMonth() + duration));
        $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', edate);
    }
}

$('#first_date').datepicker({
    onSelect: updateEndDate
})
$('select[name="duration"]').change(updateEndDate)

$('#end_date').datepicker({});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/77hrj/)